# Android - How do I specify weight programmatically for a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I want to do something like this programmatically -

```
<LinearLayout>
  <RelativeLayout1 weight = 1>
  <RelativeLayout2 weight = 3>
  <RelativeLayout3 weight = 1>
<LinearLayout>
```

It does not let me do a setWeight programmatically. However, I do see that RelativeLayout has an android:layout_weight parameter in XML. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you add the RelativeLayout to the LinearLayout using addView you have to provide a LinearLayout.LayoutParams, something like this :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, weight);
linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout, params);
```

Reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)