# What is the screen height of an android device as thrown by metrics?

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I'm writing an app that I want it to work with different screen sizes.

While in portrait mode I divide the screen height by 5 in order to set it the result as the height for text views. Hence no matter what screen there should allways be five textviews.

I have a tablet with a 1280 pixel height, which display metrics height returns as 1232. In my phone with 1980, display metrics height shows 1776. These are the values that I divide by 5.

I see the 5 textviews in my tablet perfectly but in my phone the lasts textview is almost entirely off the screen. So my question is what is the height that is returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That height returned is the screen height, minus the height of the notification bar.  But you still have things like the action bar taking space.

Comment: Seems about right. I found codes to calculate the action bar and Navigation Bar height and substracted them from the height and that was enough to fix my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dividing and do all the complicate math...

If you use a LinearLayout, you can set the weights of your TextViews to fit the screen nicely.
Just set all their weights to **1** and their height to **0dp**.

So, if tou have 4 TextViews, they will be as tall as the 25% of the usable height.
If you have 5 (which is your case),  they will be as tall as the 20% of the usable height.

And you'll avoid headaches.

Comment: I can't my layout is completely defined programatically, because it is dynamic and it is much more complicated than that. I simplified the problem because that was the core of my problem

Comment: It is possible to do that programmatically: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/6073437/2649012](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6073437/2649012)