# how to show/hide layout on button click

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to have two relativelayout in first relativelayout have map and in second relativelayout i have the list..,i want on starting only layout with map will be visible on screen with a button,,when i click on button then layout with listview get open from right side with new new button on the top of it,,and prevoius button get hide.and screen get divided with two parts with different layouts..i have done some thing but from starting onward m getting half half screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ListView_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ListView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/getdirection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Get Directions" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" >
        </fragment>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Get Directions" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
 show = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.getdirection);
         show1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hide);
         rt = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl_ListView2);
show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            if(rt.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE)
                            {
                                rt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }
                           show.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                        }
                    });
show1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            if(rt.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                            {
                                rt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            }
                           show1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                        }
                    });
```

Comment: set the visibility of the layout on button click to visible

Comment: Try to use visibility GONE instead of INVISIBLE.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

You are getting layout1 in half screen from starting due to weight property. You can try not giving weight in starting and give it programatically on button click.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);  //hide old button
        layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //show layout2
        //set Relativelayout 1 to half screen
        RelativaLayout.LayoutParams params = layout1.getLayoutParams(); 
        params.weight = 0.5;
        layout1.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ PurpleDroid my question is on activity start only map will be visible on screen and a button..,and on button click screen get divided into 2 halfs ..1 wll display map and other will display list

Comment: i dont know why but params.weight retuning me error..,not taking weight as a property of param

Comment: @user3683036 Try LinearLayout.LayoutParams instead of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6073437/1777090)

Comment: it didnt help me. @PurpleDroid

Answer (score 1):

Set visibility as **Gone** instead of **Invisible**

Answer (score 0):

```
 button.setOnClickListener(this);
    public void onClick(View v) {
    layoutid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve and what is happening i cant understand you question above

Comment: @ Hak Hak my question is on activity start only map will be visible on screen and a button..,and on button click screen get divided into 2 halfs ..1 wll display map and other will display list.right now on start  m getting dividing screen that i want on button click

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `isShown()` as suggested by Amiya

```
<b>
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   if(button1.isShown()) {

   // Your_Staff
    }
    else{
          // Your_Staff
    }
}
});
</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my view you did not set the orientation  in the `LinearLayout` to be vertical for the two RelativeLayouts. I also suggests you put the map and `Button` in a `FrameLayout` as well instead of `RelativeLayout`.